# Pandas (Python): How to apply values to similar row?

Tags: python, pandas

sorry for the badly phrased question, currently only the first hour is updated with holiday.

e.g.

- 2013-01-01 00:00:00 - New Years Day
- 2013-01-01 00:00:00 - None
- 2013-01-01 00:00:00 - None

I would like to apply similar holidays to the same date using Pandas (Python).

What would be the most efficient method to apply the holiday to the same dates, there are a number of other holidays to apply as well?

Thank you in advance!

[Screenshot of CSV in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsvTN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have only the first hour of a day listed with a holiday.  Here is a small sample of a dataframe with two months of data and three holidays on three separate days.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'temp':np.random.randint(50,110, 60*24)}, index=pd.date_range('2013-01-01', periods=(60*24), freq='H'))

df['Holiday'] = np.nan

df.loc['2013-01-01 00:00:00', 'Holiday'] = 'New Years Day'
df.loc['2013-02-02 00:00:00', 'Holiday'] = 'Groundhog Day'
df.loc['2013-02-14 00:00:00', 'Holiday'] = "Valentine's Day"
```

Now, let's use `groupby` with `day` from DatetimeIndex and `ffill`:

```
df['Holiday'] = df.groupby(df.index.day)['Holiday'].ffill()
```

Let's look at a few records:

```
print(df.head(40))
print(df['2013-02-02'])
print(df['2013-02-13':'2013-02-15'])
```

Output:

```
                     temp        Holiday
2013-01-01 00:00:00    51  New Years Day
2013-01-01 01:00:00    71  New Years Day
2013-01-01 02:00:00    61  New Years Day
2013-01-01 03:00:00    90  New Years Day
2013-01-01 04:00:00    77  New Years Day
2013-01-01 05:00:00    69  New Years Day
2013-01-01 06:00:00    50  New Years Day
2013-01-01 07:00:00    99  New Years Day
2013-01-01 08:00:00    86  New Years Day
2013-01-01 09:00:00    72  New Years Day
2013-01-01 10:00:00    89  New Years Day
2013-01-01 11:00:00    62  New Years Day
2013-01-01 12:00:00    53  New Years Day
2013-01-01 13:00:00    91  New Years Day
2013-01-01 14:00:00    51  New Years Day
2013-01-01 15:00:00    93  New Years Day
2013-01-01 16:00:00    97  New Years Day
2013-01-01 17:00:00    83  New Years Day
2013-01-01 18:00:00    87  New Years Day
2013-01-01 19:00:00    58  New Years Day
2013-01-01 20:00:00    84  New Years Day
2013-01-01 21:00:00    92  New Years Day
2013-01-01 22:00:00   106  New Years Day
2013-01-01 23:00:00   104  New Years Day
2013-01-02 00:00:00    78            NaN
2013-01-02 01:00:00   104            NaN
2013-01-02 02:00:00    96            NaN
2013-01-02 03:00:00   103            NaN
2013-01-02 04:00:00    60            NaN
2013-01-02 05:00:00    87            NaN
2013-01-02 06:00:00   108            NaN
2013-01-02 07:00:00    85            NaN
2013-01-02 08:00:00    67            NaN
2013-01-02 09:00:00    61            NaN
2013-01-02 10:00:00    91            NaN
2013-01-02 11:00:00    79            NaN
2013-01-02 12:00:00    99            NaN
2013-01-02 13:00:00    82            NaN
2013-01-02 14:00:00    75            NaN
2013-01-02 15:00:00    90            NaN
                     temp        Holiday
2013-02-02 00:00:00    82  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 01:00:00    58  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 02:00:00   102  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 03:00:00    90  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 04:00:00    79  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 05:00:00    50  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 06:00:00    50  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 07:00:00    83  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 08:00:00    80  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 09:00:00    50  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 10:00:00    52  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 11:00:00    69  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 12:00:00   100  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 13:00:00    61  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 14:00:00    62  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 15:00:00    76  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 16:00:00    83  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 17:00:00   109  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 18:00:00   109  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 19:00:00    81  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 20:00:00    52  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 21:00:00   108  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 22:00:00    68  Groundhog Day
2013-02-02 23:00:00    75  Groundhog Day
                     temp          Holiday
2013-02-13 00:00:00    93              NaN
2013-02-13 01:00:00    93              NaN
2013-02-13 02:00:00    74              NaN
2013-02-13 03:00:00    97              NaN
2013-02-13 04:00:00    58              NaN
2013-02-13 05:00:00   103              NaN
2013-02-13 06:00:00    79              NaN
2013-02-13 07:00:00    65              NaN
2013-02-13 08:00:00    72              NaN
2013-02-13 09:00:00   100              NaN
2013-02-13 10:00:00    66              NaN
2013-02-13 11:00:00    60              NaN
2013-02-13 12:00:00    95              NaN
2013-02-13 13:00:00    51              NaN
2013-02-13 14:00:00    71              NaN
2013-02-13 15:00:00    58              NaN
2013-02-13 16:00:00    58              NaN
2013-02-13 17:00:00    98              NaN
2013-02-13 18:00:00    61              NaN
2013-02-13 19:00:00    63              NaN
2013-02-13 20:00:00    57              NaN
2013-02-13 21:00:00   102              NaN
2013-02-13 22:00:00    69              NaN
2013-02-13 23:00:00    86              NaN
2013-02-14 00:00:00    94  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 01:00:00    64  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 02:00:00    62  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 03:00:00    59  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 04:00:00    93  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 05:00:00    99  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 06:00:00    64  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 07:00:00    80  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 08:00:00    89  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 09:00:00    96  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 10:00:00    60  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 11:00:00    76  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 12:00:00    82  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 13:00:00    65  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 14:00:00    90  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 15:00:00    62  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 16:00:00    64  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 17:00:00    98  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 18:00:00    52  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 19:00:00    72  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 20:00:00   108  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 21:00:00    85  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 22:00:00    87  Valentine's Day
2013-02-14 23:00:00    62  Valentine's Day
2013-02-15 00:00:00   106              NaN
2013-02-15 01:00:00    82              NaN
2013-02-15 02:00:00    77              NaN
2013-02-15 03:00:00    52              NaN
2013-02-15 04:00:00    94              NaN
2013-02-15 05:00:00    71              NaN
2013-02-15 06:00:00    95              NaN
2013-02-15 07:00:00    96              NaN
2013-02-15 08:00:00    71              NaN
2013-02-15 09:00:00    69              NaN
2013-02-15 10:00:00    85              NaN
2013-02-15 11:00:00    92              NaN
2013-02-15 12:00:00   106              NaN
2013-02-15 13:00:00    77              NaN
2013-02-15 14:00:00    65              NaN
2013-02-15 15:00:00   104              NaN
2013-02-15 16:00:00    98              NaN
2013-02-15 17:00:00   107              NaN
2013-02-15 18:00:00   106              NaN
2013-02-15 19:00:00    67              NaN
2013-02-15 20:00:00    59              NaN
2013-02-15 21:00:00    81              NaN
2013-02-15 22:00:00    56              NaN
2013-02-15 23:00:00    75              NaN
```

Note: In this dataframe your datetime column is in the index.

Answer (score 2):

Using a library called [holidays](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) together with pandas apply could be a great solution to your problem. Here is a short contained example example

```
import pandas as pd
import holidays

us_holidays = holidays.UnitedStates()

# Create a sample DataFrame. You can just use your own
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30'), columns=['date'])

data['holiday'] = data['date'].apply(lambda x: us_holidays.get(x))
print(data)
```

Output

```
        date                      holiday
0  2020-01-01               New Year's Day
1  2020-01-02                         None
2  2020-01-03                         None
3  2020-01-04                         None
4  2020-01-05                         None
5  2020-01-06                         None
6  2020-01-07                         None
7  2020-01-08                         None
8  2020-01-09                         None
9  2020-01-10                         None
10 2020-01-11                         None
11 2020-01-12                         None
12 2020-01-13                         None
13 2020-01-14                         None
14 2020-01-15                         None
15 2020-01-16                         None
16 2020-01-17                         None
17 2020-01-18                         None
18 2020-01-19                         None
19 2020-01-20  Martin Luther King, Jr. Day
20 2020-01-21                         None
21 2020-01-22                         None
22 2020-01-23                         None
23 2020-01-24                         None
24 2020-01-25                         None
25 2020-01-26                         None
26 2020-01-27                         None
27 2020-01-28                         None
28 2020-01-29                         None
29 2020-01-30                         None
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Heikki, but is there anyway I can maintain the format of the CSV? (Please see attached screenshot) I would have to perform an EDA on this dataset (Screenshot shown, is not the full dataset) Sorry if I am not making much sense, I am very new at this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the apply method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

The input to this is the function you want to be applied to each row. And in this case "axis" should be zero so that it is applied to each row.